# Why does full-text search inside titles return error

Tags: full-text-search, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

When I perform full-text search with Wikipedia API, I can not narrow it to titles only (srwhat=title).

So while search anywhere (default) 
  http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=sql&srnamespace=14&format=xml

returns results, if I add srwhat=title, I got an error:

```
<api servedby="mw69">
  <error code="srsearch-title-disabled" info="title search is disabled"/>
</api>
```

This error is even listed in the docs ( http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search ), but without any explanation.

Comment: It seems there is a way to workaround this. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624431/wikipedia-api-search-titles-generator

Comment: [opensearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=opensearch) is a good alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the search engine Wikipedia uses (Lucene, I believe) does not support title search.

Comment: You mean, there are features planned in the API that could not be supported due to particular engine used?

Comment: MediaWiki is not just Wikipedia. Other wikis don't use Lucene, so they can support title search. But Wikipedia doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, looking at the searching help, I also found that I can use the same operators in the search (so "intitle:" should help) so no problem with not supporting titles directly

Answer (score 7):

Actually, there is a way to workaround this, just add `intitle:` prefix to your search term:

```
srsearch=intitle:sql
```

You can find an explanation here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching#Parameters