# wikipedia api search titles generator

Tags: search, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Trying to search tiles through the api using a generator.
I notice that there are two possible generators, with both I have problems:

- prefix search - doesn't work well if I have multiple words and the order is reversed in the query (for example "brian adams" would return an answer, however "adams brian" does not
- search - seems to not allow searching by titles, only by text which returns low-quality results.

Anyone knows of a way around this?

Answer (score 7):

"srwhat=title" is disabled, so you should use "intitle:" in your search query:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srnamespace=0&srprop=timestamp&&srsearch=intitle:adams%20brian

for more info please check this page:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search